# Sorting full collection vs Binary Insertion sorting into a new collection

Tags: java, sorting, time-complexity

What is faster on an average (ignore optimal cases):

```
int[] arr = new arr[]{1,10,4,3,20,9};
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

VS Binary insertion sort into a new array (higher space complexity)

```
int[] arr =  new arr[]{1,10,4,3,20,9};
int[] arr2 = new arr2[arr.length];

for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr2[i] = insertionSort(arr2, 0, arr2.length, arr[i]);
}

public void insertionSort(int[] arr2, int min, int max, int val){
     // perform binary search insertion...
}
```

or are they the same thing?

Option 1: assuming we use sorting method with an average of (nlog(n))
Option 2: the insertion sort into new array will also be n*log(n) as well but, I think faster because the log(n) goes from log(1) -> log(n) as it fills up the array (not a flat log(n) like in option 1)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Binary insertion sort** employs a binary search to determine the correct location to insert new elements, and therefore performs ⌈log2 n⌉ comparisons in the worst case, which is O(n log n).

> **The algorithm as a whole still has a running time of O(n2) on average
> because of the series of swaps required for each insertion.**

where as `Arrays.sort(arr);` uses dual **pivot quicksort time complexity**
**Dual pivot quick sort** is a little bit faster than the original single pivot quicksort. ... But still, the worst case will remain O(n^2) when the array is already sorted in an increasing or decreasing order.

hence `Arrays.sort(arr)` is better in most of the use case.

Comment: Binary insertion sort does log n _comparisons_, but inserting into the array takes O(n) for each iteration, making the whole thing O(n^2).

Comment: Oh wow - i cant believe i forgot that shifting the entire array is not a O(1) that makes complete sense

Comment: Also thanks Hades, this makes a lot of sense. I will have to look into dual pivot quick sort. This is the first time i am learning about this

Comment: @JoseAlejandroDuque u can upvote & accept if u feels it helped u :)